# Get common characters from strings

Tags: python, string, boolean

I'm looking for the way of comparing two strings and being able to get back, as separate strings:

- All the common characters,
- The uncommon characters, (all characters but without the common ones)
- Characters that are unique to one string.

Example:

```
A = "123 ABC"
B = "135 AZ"

thingamajigger(A, B)  # would give all these:

intersect = "13 A"  # (includes space)
exclusion = "2BCZ5"
a_minus_b = "2BC"
b_minus_a = "5Z"
```

`a_minus_b` is quite simple... but if there's one of those fancy one-liner ways to pull it off, then I'm open.

```
for i in B:
    A = A.replace(i, "")
```

It's a bit like boolean operations on strings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
s = set("123 ABC")
t = set("135 AZ")
intersect = s & t # or s.intersection(t)
exclusion = s ^ t # or s.symmetric_difference(t)
a_minus_b = s - t # or s.difference(t)
b_minus_a = t - s # or t.difference(s)
```

Comment: Wow... of course... and then you can just use "".joint(set) to squash it into a string! Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph: It *is* beautiful, isn't it? :-)

Comment: The only thins is, sets only contain unique elements. So, say I wanted to subtract _"!"_ from _"Hello!"_. Using _set("Hello!") - set("!")_ would give _"Helo"_. But using the alternative _a_minus_b_ above works. :)

Comment: @Joseph: I see. If that's what you want, I'd use `"".join([c for c in A if c not in set(B)])` though; it's vastly more efficient (additive in the lengths vs. multiplicative in the lengths).