# Counting common characters between two strings in python

Tags: python, character

I have a code I've been working on, but it doesn't output as well as I need it to. I had to make up my own algorithm for a code in python that counts characters in input strings. It is like haystack in a needle method but I'm not supposed to use any text comparing methods, like count() and findall(). I would like my code to count character by character and doesn't count overlapping letters. I'm looking for longest common substring. Here is my code so far, but it outputs still wrong. When I type "aaaaa" in the String1 field and "aa" in the String 2 field, it outputs 1, but it should output 2, because there are 2 "aa"s in the "aaaaa" without overlapping.

```
    test1 = input("String1: ")
    test2 = input("String2: ")

    common = {}
    if len(test1)<len(test2):
    for letter in test1:
        if letter in test2:
            common[letter]= 1

    else:
    for letter in test2:
        if letter in test1:
            common[letter]= 1
    print (len(common))
```

Comment: Can you give more examples?

Comment: Are you asking about [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) or [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)?

Comment: You can use `set` solution from following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666963/python-get-common-characters-from-strings

Comment: @Mell this is your second question on the same topic that, despite being much better than previous, it is still not clearly stated and is too broad - we won't wrote the whole code for you.

Comment: @RafałRawicki I'm sorry, I'm new at this and because english isn't my main language, it's hard to express myself. I want the code to read "String1" character by character and look for the string that I typed in "String2". I have this code that I wrote here, but I'm in a dead end because I haven't got a clue where to next...

Comment: @Mell don't be sorry, everyone is new at something. Just edit the question to be more precise :) using your example I still don't have an idea what you want to achieve. Please look at the two wikipedia articles I linked above.

Comment: I edited it a bit, I'm looking for longest common substring.

Answer (score 1):

So one of the problems with your code is the way you are counting the character occurrences, if you do "aaaa" and "aa" the output like you said is 2 but in your current code it will be 1 regardless. Here's the fix.

```
import re
test1 = input("String1: ")
test2 = input("String2: ")

common = {}
if len(test1) < len(test2):
     for letter in test1:
         if letter in test2:
             common[letter] = len(re.findall(letter, test2))

else:
     for letter in test2:
         if letter in test1:
             common[letter] = len(re.findall(letter, test1))
for word, count in common.items():
    print("{0}\t{1}".format(word,count))
```

Comment: You can shorten the `if letter in common` blocks by using the pattern `common[letter] = common.get(letter, 0) + 1` or using a `defaultdict`.

Comment: Thank you, but it still outputs the same way as my code. If I type in String1 "aaaaa" and in string2 "aa", it supposed to output 2, because there is two "aa"'s in string1, but it outputs just 1.

Comment: The problem is you are printing the length of the dictionary, and not the actual counts. I've edited the code to fix that.

Comment: But if I type in the String1 : "riding riding riding" and in the string2: "ri", then it still outputs wrong. I know I can't explain well but the code has to check letter by letter but when the user inputs a phrase, then it has to search multiple phrases also, not only letters. How can I change the code to do that? @Seekheart

Comment: @Mell I just edited the code to take that in to account... please in the future explain this clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
str1=input()
str2=input()

cnt=0
if len(str1)<len(str2):
    for i in str1:
       if i in str2:
           cnt+=1
else:
    for i in str2:
        if i in str1:
            cnt+=1
print(cnt)
```

Comment: You have only code as an answer. Could you please add some text to it, this will make it easier to understand what you are doing for all user in future.

Comment: Yes, while this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.